# Embed C# code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In my `.aspx` file I have a button

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" ValidationGroup="SearchRoles" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="BtnSearch_Click" />
```

Normally in the `.cs` file if I needed to call any methods for the button I would call `BtnSearch.method()` but I have a function in the JavaScript for `EditClick()` and I would like to call `BtnSearch.Enable = false` but I get an exception. How would I disable this button in the JavaScript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery. These days, you won't normally see a website which doesn't use jQuery or Javascript Framework.

Since you cannot predict Server Control ID at run-time, you want to use `#<%= SearchButton.ClientID %>`.

[image]

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search"
    ValidationGroup="SearchRoles" CausesValidation="true"
    OnClick="SearchButton_Click" />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="DisableButtonCheckBox" />
    Check to disable button
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#DisableButtonCheckBox").click(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $("#<%= SearchButton.ClientID %>").prop("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $("#<%= SearchButton.ClientID %>").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I personally do not like using `ClientIDMode="static"`, unless I do not have any other option.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the

```
OnClientClick=""
```

attribute in the asp button?

Then run inline code similar to

```
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
```

Final view:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" ValidationGroup="SearchRoles" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="BtnSearch_Click" OnClientClick="$(this).prop('disabled', true);"/>
```